# Third party library throwing compilation errors when being included in project

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2015, protocol-buffers

I am trying to write a plugin for a program, and I am using protobuf for communication. I had to install the protobuf libraries from source, and this was done without any compilation errors. However, after I link and include the appropriate libraries and headers, respectively, I get errors coming from the protobuf headers, like `may not be initialized`. It appears to be linking correctly as there are no undefined sources and including correctly for intellisense is finding the symbols in those files.
I have tried disabling the `treat warnings as errors` and the `sdl` compiler flags, but these do not solve my problem.
To clarify, the problem is:

```cpp
static constexpr int kMessageSetMessageNumber = 3;
```

says that it `may not be initialized` and

```cpp
static const int kMessageSetItemStartTag = GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_WIRE_FORMAT_MAKE_TAG(
      kMessageSetItemNumber, WireFormatLite::WIRETYPE_START_GROUP);
```

which `must be a constant expression`.
And, again, when building from source in VS2015, these errors do not appear; they appear when I try using the protobuf lib and include directories that were just built and installed. This lead me to thinking of the flags solution as stated above.
In my top level CMakeLists, I have

```
    FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf EXACT 3.13.0.0 REQUIRED PATHS "$ENV{ProgramW6432}/protobuf")
```

which gets the lib and include for protobuf successfully
and in my subdirectoy, the CMakeLists is

```
project(ZMQReceiverV2)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    ./ZMQReceiverV2.cpp
    ./ZMQReceiverV2.h
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ...
    ${Protobuf_LIBRARY}
    libprotobuf
    libprotobuf-lite
    libprotoc
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    SYSTEM PUBLIC
    ...
    PUBLIC ${protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Though, I am thinking the issue is compiler configuration or of this nature, I included my cmakelists, incase you think the problem lies with that.

Can you help me resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with full compiler output

Comment: Are you compiling *your* code as C++11?

Comment: @Bojte I am ```set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")```. I am working on a min example too btw Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your answers. The issue was that I had two installs of the library, and only one was working. So after removing the messed up one and fixing my cmake variables, I was able to compile my plugin.